# Am I Required to Have Some Form of a Navigation Controller to Navigate Views?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building an app with a `tableView` and a couple details pages. I started with the `masterViewController` template, but found that I wanted to customize my `tableView` layout, so I deleted the `navigationController` and added a `viewController` with a `tableView` inside. Everything is working great, except for the fact that I can't get out of the `detailView`. I added a navigation bar to the top of the `detailView` with a `cancel` button, but the `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` isn't working (I'm guessing because there is no nav controller). I've also tried using the `popToViewController` method, but couldn't get that to work either.

My question is then: What do I have to do to be able to "pop" views? I'm assuming that the views are being pushed somewhere when I go from the `tableView` to the `detailView` via the segue, so how do I go back? Do I have to use some form of `navigationController`?

Any direction or help would be great!

Comment: You should put the nav controller back. Why did you remove it (how did it prevent you from modifying the table view)?

Comment: Knowing how to manipulate view controllers is a very essential part of iOS programming. If you're new to iOS, you should read the two documents that are linked at the top of the UIViewController Class Reference. How to transition between controllers is well covered in these docs.

Comment: Thanks Wain, I thought about what everyone said, and put back the nav controller, and just used a different table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: yes

dont delete the navigation controller, otherwise you wont be able to pop and push views (you can still use modal transitions though)

all a navigation controller really is, is a manager for a array of viewControllers. if you look at the `self.navigationController.viewControllers` property, you can access the navigation chain, and change it how you want by putting it into a `NSMutableArray` and doing changes and assigning it back. just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Using NavigationController will be a good choice according to me..

If you are using NavigationController, you could use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` instead of popToRootViewController to pop and to push

```
[self.navigationController pushViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you use "views", then use `[self.view removeFromSuperview]` to remove the whole view, or remove all views use this:

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) 
  {
     [view removeFromSuperview];
  }
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score -1):

in order to navigate through your app, your app requires a navigation controller, if you are setting up the app in storyboard you can drag the navigation controller from the right side and then link it to a view controller.

your popping code probably isn't working because you have no navigation controller aka self.navigationController is nil,

if you are making the app mostly in code you may can allocate a navigation contorller

```
UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: masterViewController];
```

from there you can push to other pages or pop to previous pages

adding a navigation bar to the top of your page in the storyboard doesn't give your view controller navigating functionality, it is simply user interface objects just sitting there, if you want to set the ui navigation bar to your actual navigation bar then you may set it in code

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBar:navigationBarProperty];
```

so to answer your question, you need a navigation controller and in the story board 
-> navigation controller -> tableView -> detailView should do the trick

Comment: The app doesn't 'require' a navigation controller, it just makes life a lot easier.